# What does the logistic function look like as a percent growth curve?

Tags: calculus, probability, curves

I know the logistic equation / logistic function looks like this sort of stretched-out S curve. And the derivative looks like this normal-function-esque hump. But the derivative is the rate of change of x/t not expressed as a *percentage change* in x.

So my question is what does the graph of the *percentage increase* in x of the logistic function, over time, look like, and what would this graph/curve be called conversationally?

Comment: Do you mean quite simply $x'(t)/x(t)$? If so, I suppose you could [graph it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gagzdjt1si) easily enough. For the most basic logistic function $1/(1+e^{-t})$, the graph looks like a reflection of the original about the $x$-axis and it's not so hard to prove that using the formula.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I am not quite sure yet, but that does seem like an interesting possibility. Thanks for the graph!